# Prove there is no complex $\sqrt{\cdot }$ on the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume $ f:\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{ 0\right\} \to\mathbb{C} $ is holomorphic and $f(z)\neq 0 $ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{ 0\right\}  $.

Is it true that there exists $ g^{2}:\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{ 0\right\} \to\mathbb{C} $ such that $g $ is holomorphic and $g^2=f $ ?

I think that $f(z)=z $ is a  counter example, since the only example of $g^2=z$ I cant think of on the whole punctured plane is $ g^{2}=e^{\frac{1}{2}\log z} $ and we would have to define $\log $ on this region which is impossible.

How can I reach an explicit contradiction?

Comment: This requires Riemann Mapping Theorem. See Theorem 13.11 in Rudin's RCA which gives various characterizartons of simply connected regions.

Comment: here we need to assume $g$ continuous (hence holomorphic) as otherwise, one can find $g^2=z$ by taking a random sign of the square root at each non zero $z$; assuming $g$ holomorphic, one gets $2g'/g=1/z$ and integrating on the unit circle one gets $2k=1$ for some integer $k$  (remembering that $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}f'dz/f=k$ by the argument principle as long as $f$ holomorphic and non zero in a neighborhood of the unit circle)

Comment: Another way: if $g:\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\to \Bbb{C}$ is a holomorphic function such that for all $z\in\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, $[g(z)]^2=z$, then since $g$ remains bounded near the origin, it has a holomorphic extension to the origin. Thus, $g$ is actually an entire function; furthermore, there is the growth restriction $|g(z)|\leq \sqrt{|z|}$ (the usual square root of a non-negative real number). This already implies $g$ is constant by Cauchy's inequalities (just follow the usual proof of Liouville's theorem). But if $g$ is constant then clearly $g^2$ is constant so cannot equal $z$.

Comment: You don't even need to require that $g$ is holomorphic -- even a _continuous_ square root defined just on $\{z: |z|=1\}$ is impossible.

Comment: @Troposphere Why?